# Como enviar um TOKEN de authorization e parâmetros para realizar um INSERT em minha API?

Tags: c#, api, token

Minha API funciona corretamente. Consigo inserir dados no banco de dados por meio dela junto ao POSTMAN, porém gostaria de fazer isso no c#.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa segunda imagem é da criação de um token meu.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, não poste código como imagem. Sempre use texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim como no POSTMAN, é preciso enviar este token num *header* da requisição.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization 
                     = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "token da API");
```